# В Firefox у service worker navigator отсутствуют permissions

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Мне нужно что бы в service worker вызывались Notifications. Соответственно мне нужно проверить пермишены. В chome это делается как

```
self.navigator['permissions'].query({ name: 'notifications' })
```

И все нормально. А вот в firefox параметр 'permissions' отсутствует.

Как можно в firefox проверить пермишены?

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно почему вы пытаетесь именно таким образом проверить разрешение для нотификаций, ведь это делается через [`Notification.permission`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Notification/permission).

Comment: В сервис воркере нету глобальной Notification